# Using C# code in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com

in one of my application, I'm calling C# methods in my C++ code. I have used the documentation  form [MSDN: How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736). I'm successful in doing the job. it is working fine in my machine. But when I deploy the same C++ code in another machine to test along with the created .tlb file from C#, my code is failing with unhandled exception in the step of "// Create the interface pointer. ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));". Please advice on the same. Thank you.

Comment: is the required .net framework installed in your target machine?

Comment: Target machine has VS10.

Comment: I don't think it may work. you will need the same .net framework which you used to compile the c# code, not visual studio. visual studio is not required

Comment: In my machine I have used same VS2010 to compile the C# code. Please advice. Do i need to register the C# dll or something?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736) make sure you followed the step copied below, and that it completed without errors. Note that it's not enough to deploy/copy the TLB file, you must actually register it along with the assembly on the target machine.

> Register the Managed DLL for Use with COM or with Native C++
>
> To use the managed DLL with COM or with native C++, you must register the assembly information of your DLL in the Windows registry.
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>   
> ...
>   5.To register the assembly information of your managed DLL in the Windows registry and to create a corresponding type library, run the following command at the Visual Studio .NET command prompt:
>
> ```
> RegAsm.exe ManagedDLL.dll /tlb:ManagedDLL.tlb /codebase
> ```

Comment: Hi dxiv, Thanks for the reply. I have registered the dll and I got the .tlb file in my machine. I have deployed the same to the target machine also. Please advice for any further  missed steps. Thank you.

Comment: @Bhavani What exactly do you mean by `deployed the same to the target machine`? It's not enough to copy them, that was the main point.

Comment: Hello dxiv, I understand its not enough to copy the .tlb file. I have registered the managed dll in my machine and used in C++. It is working fine. when I use the C++ dll in another machine, I'm getting errors, obviously because the managed dll is not registered in the target machine.Can you suggest a way to register the managed dll through code or any other solution to make my code work in any other machine. Thank you.

Comment: @Bhavani As dxiv says, you have to run **regasm** on **every machine** you copy it to, not just your development machine.

Comment: Hello Micky, Thank you for the comment. Can you please guide me the procedure, if any, to register my dll. As it is manually impossible to register the dll using RegAsm.exe in all the machine where I'm going to deploy my code, please suggest me a way. Thank you.

Comment: @Bhavani _"As it is manually impossible to register the dll using RegAsm.exe in all the machine"_ - what are you talking about?  If you are deploying it, you can run regasm

Comment: @Bhavani Regasm is a standard tool part of the .NET runtime (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx). If your application has an installer, then that one could call `regasm` on your app's behalf. Otherwise, if you mean an [xcopy deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment) where your main app would register dependent assemblies on the fly, then that's technically possible but it's a completely differrent question from what you originally asked here. Feel free to rephrase it - with full details on what your context and assumptions are - then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I found below code working.

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;

    shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
    shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
    shExecInfo.lpFile = L"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\RegAsm.exe";
    shExecInfo.lpParameters = L"C:\\Test\\WebServices.dll /tlb:C:\\Test\\WebServices.tlb /codebase";
    shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    shExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
    shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

    ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

Use the above code in your C++ function for auto registering the managed dll.
Gentle suggestion, People come here to seek help of experts as people are confused and dont know the right path. Reducing the ratings or score in such cases is not a decent job. Thanks all.